# How to create an UPSERT command?

Tags: oracle

I want to replace all instances of INSERTs in one script by another keyword that would update data instead of inserting data. With mySQL, I could use UPSERT or REPLACE. But with Oracle, I can't use MERGE because the MERGE syntax is more complex so I can't just change one keyword. Any idea ?+

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
-- would become :
UPSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't do that, i.e. simply search/replace `INSERT` with `MERGE` and expect it to work. It won't, because syntax would be wrong. As you've already noticed, `MERGE` is more complex than pure `INSERT` and/or `UPDATE` so ... you're out of luck.

However, if you're willing to write some more code (completely rewrite `INSERT`s you currently have), it would be OK but requires some effort.

Answer (score 0):

*IF* it all refers to the same table and the column names are all in the same order, you may be able to get away with changing it to call to a stored procedure

> call upsert_proc (value1, value2, value3, ...);

You'd have to code that procedure to do the merge or do the insert with an exception handler to do the update.